# Firebase Firestore key-specific write permissions in a single document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am making an upvote/downvote system using firestore. I have items which all have unique ids and I want to create a 'votes' collection where the key is the item id and the key:value pairs are the uid's of the voters and their vote. My schema is:

```
votedDocumentId: {
   user1Id: user1Vote,
   user2Id: user2Vote,
   ...
}
```

I want to restrict permissions for writes based on the user Id key that the user is trying to update, they should only be able to change their own vote, not another users vote:

```
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /votes/{votedDocumentId} {
        allow read;
        allow update: if request.auth.uid == ???
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible with the current rules. In my opinion this is a scenario where you should make use of a cloud function.

Otherwise you could index the documents by the user Ids which would make it easier for you the setup the rules:

```
match /votes/{userId} {
    allow read;
    allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId
}
```

In there you could query for the documentId, though you would have a data overkill depending on the activity of the users on you platform.